# Magento 1.9 hide nav-bar (top-menu) for new controller in admin page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have added the following code in controller page, but still the nav-bar is not hiding..

```
         $this->loadLayout();
         $this->getLayout()->unsetBlock('header');
         $this->getLayout()->unsetBlock('footer');
         $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
            'my_block_name_here',
            array('template' => 'ddevs/example_core_block.phtml')
        );

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        $this->renderLayout();
```

Comment: Or, is there any way to get the layout like the Dataflow-profile page?

Answer (score 2):

Better use layout xml for this case.
If you want remove menu than you can only set blank template for menu block. If you will remove `menu` block than you will get fatal error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object  in /var/www/project/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 104

So try use code below and create `page/blank.phtml` file (of course you can rename this file like you want).

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_controller_action>
        <reference name="menu">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/blank.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="footer" />
        <remove name="header" />
    </adminhtml_controller_action>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to remove from controller,

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->unsetChild('header');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->unsetChild('footer');
$this->renderLayout();
```

(or)

```
 $this->loadLayout();
 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->unsetChild('header')->unsetChild('footer');
 $this->renderLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in xml file to unset the block by name,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <module_controller_action>
        <!-- <remove name="header"/>
        <remove name="footer"/> -->
        <reference name="root">                
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>header</name></action>
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>footer</name></action>
        </reference>
    </module_controller_action>
</layout>
```

Comment: I tried by adding the above code in layout file, but no luck.. Is there anything am i missing?